# Email reminders - correct timezone

Tags: date, email, timezone, sendgrid, sendgrid-templates

I want to send email reminders to users and include the date and time in the email itself. How do I make sure that those are displayed in a user's current timezone, especially when the user might have traveled in the time he saved the record in the database?

Is the only way to just display the date in the email and include the timezone next to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

When you send an email to a user, unless it is in response to a request that includes the user's current time zone, you cannot know for sure what time zone they are in. So, your suggestion to include the time zone in the date and time is a good idea.

One other suggestion is that you could send them an attachment with a calendar invite that includes the time of the event in UTC that can then be read and displayed by their calendar application in their own time zone.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I indeed decided to remove the time/date information and included invites – just as you suggested!